# Java scroll text on canvas

Tags: java, animation, canvas, awt, hardware-acceleration

I'm making an application where I need to scroll some text on a [`java.awt.Canvas`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) - at the moment I'm doing this by constantly calling the `repaint()` method, and overriding the `paint()` method in `Canvas` to adjust the position each time the method is called and then draw the string at the given position.

This works, but it really eats through CPU something silly for something so simple. Is there a better, hardware accelerated way to do the task? I've tried using `VolatileImage` but for some reason that made the performance noticeably worse.

I need to use `Canvas` not `JPanel` - I'm using VLCJ in the same project, and it needs a heavyweight component on which to play the video.

Comment: This will probably look like a silly question, but how often is "constantly"? Are you using a timer to call `repaint` every so many milliseconds?

Comment: @lhballoti Not at all, I'm calling repaint every 40ms or so. I'm not calling it as fast as is humanly (machinely) possible if that's what you mean :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [*Double Buffering and Page Flipping*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html) in this context.

Addendum: You might look at pre-rendering the full text into a depth-compatible `BuffreredImage`; `drawImage()` does better of it doesn't have to scale or change depths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm already using double buffering (I do as standard whenever it comes to using graphics / animation.)

Comment: Pre-rendering what I could seems to have cut down the CPU usage noticeably, thanks for that. CPU usage is still hanging around 30% or so. No particular profiling seems to help, the painting itself seems pretty spread out over the statements with no particular one jumping out.